Currency decimals issue CDS to SAC
I have developed CDS view that is consumed by SAP Analytics Cloud. One of the columns represent financial balance.

As you might see the value is formatted with two decimals (typical for SAP DBs I believe). For all the currencies the balances are send in this format - two decimal places - regardless if those are currencies with no decimal places (JPY or HUF) or more than 2. I have already used CAST and below annotations:

but they seem to affect i.e. what's visible as converted value in SE16N

but not what is fetched by SAC.
Is there any option to modify a CDS to have a proper data (correct decimals depending on currency) to be sent to SAC
